# Jquery hover not working after Ajax content is loaded

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue where a hover event I have does not work after an ajax load, it only works on initial page load... This is the code I am using currently:

```
    $(".table tbody tr").hover(
        function () {
            $(this).children('td').children('.operation').children('.btn-group').fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            $(this).children('td').children('.operation').children('.btn-group').fadeOut();
        }
    );
```

I know that I need to use the $(document).on() as the selector but I am unsure of the correct syntax to do the functionality as in original code. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Poster's own solution from the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15161947/jquery-hover-not-working-after-ajax-content-is-loaded/15162051#comment21352400_15162051). True, `document` (or any ancestor that is not affected by the ajax call) must be used.

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find('.btn-group').fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find('.btn-group').fadeOut();
    }
}, '.table tbody tr');
```

**ORIGINAL**

```
$(".table tbody").on("hover","tr",
    function () {
        $(this).children('td').children('.operation').children('.btn-group').fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).children('td').children('.operation').children('.btn-group').fadeOut();
    }
);
```

**EDIT**

True, `hover` is old-school, and doesn't work in this instance I guess!
Try this:

```
$(".table tbody").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).children('td').children('.operation').children('.btn-group').fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).children('td').children('.operation').children('.btn-group').fadeOut();
    }
},'tr');
```

And I'm not exactly sure what you're doing, but this might even be shorter:

```
$(".table tbody").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).find('.btn-group').fadeIn();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $(this).find('.btn-group').fadeOut();
    }
},'tr');
```

Comment: Note, the "hover" pseudo event is no longer supported in jQuery 1.9 http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#hover-pseudo-event Might as well take this as an opportunity to make the code compatible with future versions of jQuery.

Comment: Hi Andrew. This seems to stop the code working entirely on initial page load and after an ajax refresh. I tried adding alerts in both functions and they do not appear either on hover of the TR

Comment: Hi Andrew many thanks for your contributions and shorter solution. I still am having issues with it working after the table contents are loaded via Ajax.

Comment: ` $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(this).find('.btn-group').fadeIn();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(this).find('.btn-group').fadeOut();
        }
    }, '.table tbody tr'); '

This ended up being the working solution after playing with your code, many thanks.

Comment: God's work. I bypass the website rules just to say this. You deserve more than a gold, Andrew.